# Docker + Springboot + postgres + JHipster = org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, jhipster

I am creating a java project with JHipster, spring boot data, and Postgres. When I try to run the application in the Docker container, I get the following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:385)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:103)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:93)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1602)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:143)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:132)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:116)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ffa9c4a.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ffa9c4a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cf4d52f5.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ffa9c4a.servletEndpointRegistrar(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory$Initializer.onStartup(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:616)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:192)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.createDeploymentManager(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:284)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
```

postgres.yml

```
  services:
    scrabble-postgresql:
        image: postgres:10.4
        #volumes:
        #     - ~/volumes/jhipster/scrabble/postgresql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=scrabble
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=

        ports:
            - 5432:5432
```

application.yml

```
version: '2'
  services:
    scrabble-app:
        image: scrabble
        environment:
            # - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://scrabble-postgresql:5432/scrabble
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10 # time for the database to boot before the application
            - SPRING_DATA_JEST_URI=http://scrabble-elasticsearch:9200
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    scrabble-postgresql:
        extends:
            file: postgresql.yml
            service: scrabble-postgresql
    scrabble-elasticsearch:
        extends:
            file: elasticsearch.yml
            service: scrabble-elasticsearch
```

application-prod.yml

```
spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: false
        livereload:
            enabled: false
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/scrabble
        username: scrabble
        password:
        hikari:
            auto-commit: false
```

Help me out, please. Thanks!

Comment: check the docker-compose logs, is your db is ready before your app starts ? your db must be ready to accept request before your app requests db connections.

Comment: The error is not complete, it should show more details; If you truncated it, please edit your question and paste full error. Also you use postgres 10;4, JHipster supported this version more than 2 years ago, so is this a new project generated by an obsolete version of JHipster, an odl project or something you modified manually after generation?

Comment: The DB is ready to accept the request.

Comment: Just edited it. I did modify it after generation. thanks

Comment: Have you checked (in debugger or logs) which jdbc url is used for your datasource? Is it the one in env variable in docker-compose file or the one in application-prod.yml? Have you tried to increase JHIPSTER_SLEEP? Have you tried to add a `depends_on` from app to db in you docker-compose file?

Comment: Success part of the log message:

2020-11-24T07:19:19.940251812Z Success. You can now start the database server using:
2020-11-24T07:19:19.940258507Z 
2020-11-24T07:19:19.940263784Z     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

Comment: The one in the application-prod.yml file. I did increase the sleep time but haven't tried to add a depends_on. Let me try that now

Comment: Thanks, @GaëlMarziou, it's okay now. I really appreciate your assistance

Comment: Great, you should post an answer  with details if you think it can be helpful for other developers.